# ¿Por que este método recursivo no finaliza en el true?

Tags: java, estructuras-de-datos, árboles-binarios

estoy haciendo un programa que si encuentra una hoja (árbol binario)igual a un dato insertado retorna true sino false, el programa entra hasta el system pero no retorna true sino false, agradezco su ayuda.

El problema parecer ser la ultima vez que se ejecuta y deja de cumplir el if así que retorna un false.

```
  public boolean hoja(Nodo raiz, int dato) {

        if (raiz != null) {
            if (raiz.dato == dato && raiz.Hder == null && raiz.Hizq == null) {
                System.out.println(raiz.dato);
                return true;
            }
            hoja(raiz.Hizq, dato);
            hoja(raiz.Hder, dato);

        }
        return false;

    }
}
```

Comment: En cual llamada del método obtienes el false?

Comment: @YemisiSCG este metodo luego lo imprimo y sale el false junto a el número que cumple con la condición, editare la pregunta y es que el problema ese debe a que cuando se ejecuta por ultima vez al terminar de recorrer el arbol deja de cumplir raiz!=null asi que retorna ese false.

Comment: Eh... Lo que pasa es que ignoras por completo el resultado de las llamadas recursivas a *hoja*... Devuelva lo que devuelva *hoja(raiz.Hizq,dato)* o *hoja(raiz.Hder, dato)*, devolverás *false*...

Comment: Además, solo devuelves *true* cuando el valor buscado está en una hoja; si encuentras el valor buscado pero está en un nodo intermedio devuelves *false*...

Comment: Si el problema es efectivamente ese, gracias por su ayuda.